# Pass Ruby array to SQL as values

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
insert into table_name (attr1, attr2) VALUES 
  (1, 2),
  (3, 4)
;
```

I want to insert values into this table 'table_name'. But I want to make it dynamic. I have values in array form in ruby, like this:

```
[[1, 2], [3, 4]]
```

How do I pass a ruby array to sql query as values?
I am using rails and postgres.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Arel::InsertManager](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/arel/Arel/InsertManager) to generate a SQL insert statement:

```
def insert_list(table_name:, columns:, values:)
  Arel::InsertManager.new.tap do |manager|
    table = Arel::Table.new(table_name)
    manager.into(table)
    columns.each do |name|
      manager.columns << table[name.to_sym]
    end
    manager.values = manager.create_values_list(values)
  end
end
```

```
insert_list(
   table_name: :foos, 
   columns: [:bar, :baz],
   values: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6], [7, 8], [9, 10]]
).to_sql

# => "INSERT INTO \"foos\" (\"bar\", \"baz\") VALUES (1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6), (7, 8), (9, 10)"
```

Comment: Absolutely beautiful. Only recommendation would be `arel_table[name]` to `arel_table[name.to_sym]` just to ensure this works whether or not columns are initially symbols.

Comment: Thanks and good suggestion @engineersmnky.

Comment: Thanks but these are too many lines and I don't know how optimal it would be. I have done it using gsub, I will post my answer

Comment: @AsbahIshaq why don't you try actually benchmarking it? The advantage of Arel is that it's portable and handles quoting. I doubt that using gsub! On a huge string will actually perform much better. https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/benchmark/rdoc/Benchmark.html

Comment: @AsbahIshaq Arel took about twice as long. 1.223581s vs 0.652518 for 300,000 rows. Thats still negible compared to how long it will take to run the query. If you have that many rows you probally want split the job into chunks anyways and use prepared statements. https://gist.github.com/maxcal/810df7d8aec5c10c12a5669cf7ac1026

Comment: @max add a little [Bobby tables](https://bobby-tables.com/) and see how that impacts things :)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have a model you can use [ActiveRecord's insert_all](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html#method-i-insert_all)

```
Model.insert_all([{attr1: 1, attr2: 2}, {attr1: 3, attr2: 4}])
```

Comment: This would be the preferred way if you actually have a model as it will use the model for typecasting. It does have a bit more overhead though.

Comment: I don't have the model, that's why I need to use sql

Answer (score 0):

join with map would work here:

```rb
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].map{|inner| inner.join(", ")}
# => ["1, 2", "3, 4"]
[[1, 2], [3, 4]].map{|inner| inner.join(", ")}.join("),\n(")
# => "1, 2),\n(3, 4"
"(" + [[1, 2], [3, 4]].map{|inner| inner.join(", ")}.join("),\n(") + ")"
# => "(1, 2),\n(3, 4)"
puts "(" + [[1, 2], [3, 4]].map{|inner| inner.join(", ")}.join("),\n(") + ")"
# (1, 2),
# (3, 4)
```

Please note that this is a simple solution. In a production app, you would need to sanitize the array values `[[1, 2], [3, 4]]` if they were coming from untrusted sources (Users!) to avoid SQL injection attacks. But this seems to be out of the scope of this question.